# Calling a method with keywords arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Ruby 2.6.3
Rails 5.2

def test_method(param1:, param2:, param3:)
end

test_method(param1: "food")
```

It is giving me the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):11
        1: from (irb):8:in `test_method'
ArgumentError (missing keywords: param2, param3)
```

I thought the point of using method parameters, is for me to be able to specify the params I want to use, when calling this method. What am I missing? I am using this in a Rails 5.2 application, if that makes a difference.

Comment: "What am I missing" - Your parameters are missing default values and are, therefore, required ones. You have to pass all of them on each call.

Comment: This fixed it. I misunderstood how keyword arguments work

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev If you turn this into an answer, I will give you credit for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are requried keyword arguments (use `something:`) and optional keyword arguments (use `something: default_value`). I think required keyword parameters should go before optional ones.

Comment: Order of required and optional keyword args doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, the official docs are not clear (required keyword arguments aren't even mentioned :S) https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments

Comment: Just try it in a console :)

Comment: It doesn't seem as if the order makes a difference

Comment: The order doesn't matter to the interpreter but I agree from a human point of view, if a parameter is required it's obviously important and should go first.